# Polyfills breaking change in Webpack5 for Vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, polyfills, webpack-5

Webpack5 in Vue3 has a breaking change that prevents starting server

I have tried add the following to my vue.config.ts

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
        http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        fs: false,
        tls: false,
        net: false,
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Or:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const nodeLibsBrowser = require('node-libs-browser');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
      fallback: nodeLibsBrowser,
    },
  },
};
```

I also tried creating a file called polyfills.js in my main directory containing:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // Polyfill for 'https' module
  window.https = require('https-browserify');
}
```

And importing it in my main.ts

None of those options worked.
With each approach I am still getting the following error for 48 different cases:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

What other options do I have?

Comment: It's unclear what's your case. I'd expect it to be XY problem. You generally don't need to polyfill http, etc, because the code that uses them isn't supposed to be evaluated on client side. The question doesn't explain "prevents starting server". What does it look like? What are error messages?

Comment: I just try to run "npm run serve"
The error I get is: "ERROR in ./node_modules/jwks-rsa/src/wrappers/request.js 2:14-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/.../myProject/node_modules/jwks-rsa/src/wrappers'"

Comment: As said, this is XY problem. You're trying to use the package that was designed to run on server side in a browser